# Configure Kerberos SSO on Moodle: KRB5KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED

Tags: apache, authentication, single-sign-on, kerberos, moodle

I'm trying to set up kerberos SSO in Moodle but I'm getting a error_code: KRB5KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED (25):

**1) I've configured kerberos on Apache:** installed kerberos, configured via /etc/krb5.cnf, and tested via kinit command getting right kerberos tickets. WORKS

**2) I've created a virtual host in Apache with a folder with kerberos authentication for testing:** create a keytab file, tested authentication through kerberos works in the testing virtual site. I get the LDAP REMOTE_USER info and passes the authentication, also kerberos traffic is generated (fetched kerberos traffic with wireshark). WORKS

**3) Configured virtual host to use kerberos to authenticate to moodle:** as shown in moodle documentation.

[Moodle Kerberos SSO documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/NTLM_authentication#Using_the_Kerberos_Auth_Module_for_Apache_on_Linux.2FUNIX_.28mod_auth_kerb.29)

**4) Configured moodle's LDAP auth plugin:** login with an LDAP user works fine. WORKS

**5) Configured NTLM options in moodle's ldap plugin:** I've tested and it does generate kerberos authentication network traffic (fetched kerberos with wireshark). But I'm getting a **KRB5KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED (25)**.

Moodle LDAP configuration (NTLM section):

```
Enable = yes
Subnetwork = 192.168.0.0/16
Authentication type = kerberos
Username format = (none)
```

[image: moodle ldap config ntlm section]

My virtual host configuration for both sites (test folder and moodle folder) is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # General
        ServerAdmin myemail@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/moodle/moodle
        ServerName mymoodle.es  
        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog logs/testing-error.log
        CustomLog logs/testing.log combined

        <Location /krb_testing>
          ## Redes para las que se ofrece SSO
          AuthType Kerberos
          AuthName "Kerberos Login"

          KrbMethodNegotiate On
          KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
          KrbServiceName HTTP/mymoodle.es@MYREALM.DOMAIN.ES
          KrbAuthRealms MYREALM.DOMAIN.ES  
          Krb5KeyTab      /etc/krb5.keytab

          ## Sin require valid-user no se produce la negociacion
          require valid-user
        </Location>

        <Directory /home/moodle/moodle/auth/ldap/>
        <Files ntlmsso_magic.php>
            AuthName "Moodle"
            AuthType Kerberos
            KrbAuthRealms MYREALM.DOMAIN.ES
            KrbServiceName HTTP/mymoodle.es@MYREALM.DOMAIN.ES
            Krb5KeyTab      /etc/krb5.keytab
            KrbMethodNegotiate on
            KrbMethodK5Passwd on
            KrbAuthoritative on
            require valid-user
        </Files>
        </Directory>           
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache version:** Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)

**Moodle version:** 2.4.7

Comment: What do you want? LDAP bind, NTLM or Kerberos?

Comment: The change your entire question to the revelant Kerberos portion.

Comment: Changed ntlm terms for kerberos, though config in moodle is made under LDAP's NTLM section

Comment: You are trying to mix to fundemantally different technologies. Try mod_auth_kerb on a simple directory before you start with Moodle.

Comment: mod_auth_kerb is correctly installed, it is working on /krb_testing directory. I got a php script under that directory and I get the logged in user credentials, if not logged I get an auth required. So apache is using kerberos correctly, the problem is virtual host or moodle configuration

Comment: if you look at vhost file both (my testsite and my moodle) are trying to athenticate via kerberos: AuthType Kerberos

Comment: I do not know what moodle is doing but it actually has to retrieve `REMOTE_USER`, that's it.

Comment: I know, that's what i do inside my php script. Moodle is supposed to do that inside ntlmsso_magic.php script, but moodle's doc is missing something I guess. But as I'm telling you kerberos on apache is working fine, so It's a moodle issue

Comment: NTLM SSO has nothing to do with Kerberos SSO. You should inquire with Moodle to clarify that. So Moodle is broken.

Comment: I guess they're missusing concepts, but configuration is in the same section. Anyway I've been able to go one step forward, now I'm getting kerberos traffic and an error_code: KRB5KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED (25)

Comment: This means that the client has to provide his password to `kinit`.

Comment: so maybe setting KrbMethodK5Passwd to off in vhost conf may work. gonna try that

Comment: that does not work. Still searching for the problem

Answer (score 0):

Today i`ve the similar situation when i was configure SSO (Kerberos). I solved the issue when i set - KrbServiceName HTTP

you should replace KrbServiceName HTTP/mymoodle.es@MYREALM.DOMAIN.ES by KrbServiceName HTTP and then SSO will be work correct.